# Fitting a glm, nothing is significant

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model

[image]
[image]
I have two models

M1: $glm(claims \sim age\_group + geo\_group + excess-1, data=insurancedata, family=Gamma(link="log")$

M2: $glm(claims \sim geo\_group+ age\_group + excess-1, data=insurancedata, family=Gamma(link="log")$

In M1 age_group is significant, in M2 geo_group is significant. But I only changed the order I wrote them in??

When I start with the nullmodel, nothing is significant when I try running "add1" towards a larger fit. Should I try with another distribution, or should I just try to add variables with my intuition? No matter what I try, nothing is significant in this tryout I am having.

Comment: What is the "-1" for in each formula?

Comment: Can you please post some model output, from both models? I guess that `age_group` and `geo_group` are factor variables, which might explain the results, as the standard model output use sequential ("type 1") tests, where this might happen. Discussed much on this site!

Comment: The text is in danish, but I hope the message is clear still. And yes it is factor variables.. I haven't found any discussion on it. You think you can help me understand the issue? Is there no difference between the models, or is there a difference?

Comment: There is no difference between the model *fits* but they use different parameterizations, *as you explicitly requested when excluding the intercept (via `-1`) in the two function calls.* (Compare the coefficient estimates, for instance, to appreciate this difference.) Please see our posts about dummy coding categorical variables and focus on those that mention a "base" or "reference" category for reporting coefficients and performing automatic testing.

Comment: Thanks!@whuber 
@CFD it is the exclusion of an intercept.